# Installing Edge Webview2 Runtime via Wix Bootstrapper

Tags: installation, wix, webview2

I am trying to install **`Edge Webview2 Runtime`** via a Wix Bootstrapper using the following code:

```
            <!-- Microsoft Edge Webview2 Runtime -->
            <ExePackage
                Id="MicrosoftEdgeWebview2"
                DisplayName="Microsoft Edge Webview2 Runtime"
                Compressed="no"
                Cache="no"
                PerMachine="yes"
                Vital ="yes"
                Permanent ="yes"
                InstallCommand="/silent /install"
                UninstallCommand="/silent /uninstall"
                Name="MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe"
                DetectCondition="MicrosoftEdgeWebview2CurrentVersion64 >= MicrosoftEdgeWebview2MinimumVersion"
                SourceFile="MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe">
                <Payload SourceFile="MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe"/>
            </ExePackage>
```

I have placed `MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe` in the Wix Bootstrapper Project. My code builds okay and I have verified that `MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe` is being included in the final executable by opening it in `7zip`.

The problem occurs when I try installing the executable. When it gets to the `Edge Webview2 Runtime`, a dialog box opens asking to locate `Webview2Setup.exe`. This is not the desired behavior as I have packaged `MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe` in the Wix project. Am I doing anything wrong here?

[**Note:** I cannot package `Edge Webview2 Runtime` as a `RemotePayload` because the certificate details are being changed between versions.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do to make it work was to replace `Compressed="yes"` with `Compressed="no"` and to remove `<Payload SourceFile="MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe"/>`